# Next.JS unused javascript slow performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, code-splitting

I am doing my first website with Next.Js and after I do the lighthouse test I get really bad performance score. It says it is for unused JavaScript. Those files are in the chunk folder. I read a lot that I should split that code in order to make the page faster, but I couldn.t find a anything about how to do it. If there is someone that knows about it, it would be a great help. Below is a screenshot of the lighthouse:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all chunks and generated code, then do a production build using `npm run build` instead of `npm run dev` when you're running it on a live server.

Comment: Thanks @Matriarx I just did the npm run build and it improved the performance to 99. I didn't delete anything yet. So, to clarify, you said that I should delete those unused files in the chunk folder? Do you think there won't be an issue if I do it??

Comment: Good.  Everything that's generated and built will just be built again once you run it again (you can delete the entire .next directory and it will be regenerated).